# PHP class write data to inaccessible property beyond the top level of an array

Tags: php, arrays, class

I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is possible but I figured I'd check it out and see what reply's I get. Below is a simple example of the class.

```
class MyClass {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function setTestData($name, $value) {
        $this->data['test'][$name] = $value;
    }

}
```

And what I'm trying to get working is the following (NOTE: only if it's easy and doesn't require any other classes or outside sources to work, and the data array always remains an array inside the class):

```
$obj = new MyClass(array('test' => array()));
$obj->test->add = 'me';
```

And I get the following messages:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property MyClass::$test has no effect in ...
Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ...

Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I've also tried changing __get to pass by reference like so:

```
public function &__get($name) {
```

This seems closer but still getting the following message, which makes sense but not sure how to alter it to work.

```
Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ...
```

So if all the above is just silly or not at all a good idea, would the following a good alternative solution?

```
$obj = new MyClass(array('test' => array()));
$obj->setTestData('add', 'me');
```

This works as expected and doesn't even use the magic methods:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [add] => me
        )

)
```

Well I'm hoping somebody can put me to rest on this. Thanks to any that reply!

---

**UPDATE: Additional Alternative:**

Still not exactly what I was looking for but pretty neato anyways..

```
class MyClass {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (!isset($this->data[$name])) {
            $this->data[$name] = new stdClass();
        } else if (is_array($this->data[$name])) {
            $this->data[$name] = @json_decode(@json_encode($this->data[$name], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), false);
        }
        return $this->data[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        return @json_decode(@json_encode($this->data), true);
    }

}
```

So when I run the following:

```
$o = new MyClass(array('test' => array()));
$o->test->value = 10;
print_r($o->data);
```

I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [test] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => 10
        )

)
```

And then if I need it to be an array I just run this:

```
printr($o->toArray());
```

to get:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [value] => 10
        )

)
```

And it also works for any depth (which I'm liking):

```
$o = new MyClass(array());
@$o->one->two->three->four->five = 100;
printr($o->toArray());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [three] => Array
                        (
                            [four] => Array
                                (
                                    [five] => 100
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Only thing I didn't like was I had to suppress the warning here using @:

```
@$o->one->two->three->four->five = 100;
```

If you don't you get this:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in ...

I don't know.. What does anybody think?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** What you are trying is not possible with PHP.

---

You could imagine of something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    public $data = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
        return null;
    }   

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }   
}

$o = new MyClass();
$o->test->val = "foo";
var_dump($o);
```

This looks like it would create a `stdClass` class object on the fly for a property which does not exist (or aren't accessible!). Having an object you can use the `->` operator to access or set public properties.

**But it does not work**, since you are getting the following message:

> PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property MyClass::$test has no effect in

It does simply not work in PHP.. The code would need to look like this:

```
$o = new MyClass();
$o->test = new stdClass();
$test = $o->test;
$test->val = "foo";
$o->test = $test;
var_dump($o);
```

**NOTE!** For the above example you don't need a `__get` or `__set`. You simply can take advantage of the fact that it is possible to add public properties to a PHP object by simply assigning a value to it.

---

**Alternative:**

What about this alternative:

```
class MyClass {

    public $data = array();

    public function data($key) {
        if(!isset($this->data[$key])) {
            $this->data[$key] = new stdClass();
        }
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

}

$o = new MyClass();
$o->data('test')->value = 10;
```

Comment: Yeah I've been able to get it to work by having the data array as an object, but I was really trying to stay away from that and maintain the data as an array. Anyways, if I run the following `$obj->test->add = 'me';` none of the magic methods get called. I figured that __get would at least show $name as "test" but I don't think it even fires.

Comment: What do you think about the alternative I've suggested? (Edited the answer)

Comment: Oh I like where you were going with that but I just don't think its going to work for me either for a couple of reasons.. One, because if I construct the data array and the key already exists it errors (Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object...), and two, it's creating objects rather than arrays. I'm really wanting the data to be completely made up of an array.

Comment: I think I'm just going to assume that what I am trying to make work is simply more complicated than it's worth. Unless you have any other ideas I'm gonna stick with the "setTestData()" function I have up top since that's doing exactly what I need. Thank you very much though!

Comment: My last couple comments were about your alternative.

Comment: Actually, from looking at your example I came up with another solution that sort of works as well.. Will append it to my post in a bit. Maybe you could let me know what you think..